# RSA - statements re $\phi(n)$, $\lambda(n)$ and $n$, given $n$,$|n|=1024bits$, and $e=65537$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, reference-request, factoring, cryptography

Assume $n=pq$, with $p,q$ primes, $e=65537$, and length of $n$, $|n|=N=1024$ bits = 309 decimal digits. $p,q$ are unknown.

I am trying to understand the information sourced from Wikipedia page on RSA better. This is not a homework question.

I assume from Wikipedia that $\phi(N)$ equals the order of the multiplicative group $Z_N^*$.

Now by definition of Euler's totient function $\phi(N)$ is also equal to $1024(1-\frac{1}{2})=512$ since $2$ is the only prime which divides $1024$.

Also $\lambda(n)=LCM(p-1,q-1)$.

Wikipedia page states $\lambda(n) | \phi(n)$, and $\phi(n) = (p-1)(q-1)$

Questions:

1. This would mean that $512=\phi(n) \ge \lambda(n) > e = 65537$  which can't be right. Am I misunderstanding something? - **Corrected assumption & now resolved**
2. What information can we deduce about $n$, $\phi(n)$ or $\lambda(n)$ - eg can we obtain a lower bound on $\phi(n)$? Eg 
   $\phi(n)=(p-1)(q-1) \ge \lambda(n) > e = 65537$ ?

   - I'm looking for useful info / ways how to reduce numbers to consider for $\phi(n)$ and $\lambda(n)$.

Comment: Your remark that $\phi(n) = 512$ is not true. $n$ is a number with about $1024$ bits. In fact $\phi(n) = (p-1)(q-1)$, so yes it is true that $\phi(n) \ge \lambda(n)$.  Since $p$ and $q$ are numbers with roughly $512$ bits, they are considerably larger than $e$.

Comment: You used $\phi(N)$ in stead of $\phi(n)$. The number $n$ has 309 decimal digits. It's pretty big. On the other hand $N$ is the number of (binary) digits of $n$. $N$ is just a rough estimate for $n$. There are MANY numbers with $N$ digits.

Comment: Ok thank you both. I have updated the information above. Now I am looking for information for the revised second question.

Comment: Any thoughts about the answer I posted two days ago, unseen?

Comment: @gerrymyerson yes helpful. I am planning to use results in your answer for a brute force algorithm for RSA. Any other results on $n$, $\phi(n)$, or $\lambda(n)$ that I could use?

Comment: I don't know what sort of result you want.

Comment: I'm also not sure about the point of a brute force algorithm for [breaking] RSA. If I knew a really useful way to narrow down the search space for $\phi(n)$, I'd be famous, or dead, and either way I don't think I'd present it as an answer on math.stackexchange. $\phi$ and $\lambda$ are both relatively prime to $e$, and they are both even, and unless $p$ or $q$ is $2$, $\phi$ is a multiple of $4$; beyond that (and the bounds in my answer), I know no way to cut down the scope of an exhaustive search.

Comment: I've removed my previous comment. I see that $\phi(n)$ being a multiple of $4$ arises from $p-1$ and $q-1$ both having factors of 2. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\phi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)=pq-(p+q)+1=n+1-(p+q)$ so a lower bound on $\phi(n)$ comes from an upper bound on $p+q$ over all pairs with $pq=n$. This occurs when $p=2$ and $q=n/2$, so $$\phi(n)\ge(n-2)/2$$ for $n$ of the form $pq$ with $p,q$ prime.

For $\lambda(n)$, the extreme case occurs when $p-1=2(q-1)$.